# Sparse Matrix Coding in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix, large-data, eigenvalue

I have a dataset in which I have a 25,000 by 25,000 matrix for each timepoint with around 60% of the cells being zeroes. I need to be able to take the eigenvalues of my matrices and reorder the columns and rows. Currently, I am running into memory errors and am considering implementing sparse matrices to save memory. Is my dataset sparse enough to do this? Would I simply use the 'sparse' and 'eigs' commands to manipulate these matrices? Thank you in advance!

Comment: add any methods or commands you have already tried to do so.

Comment: Have you tried a small example? Something like `X=magic(1000);X(600:1000,:)=0;Y=sparse(X)`. Then try `memory`. I suspect you end up with more memory consumed by the sparse matrix, because it also has to store indices (don't have MATLAB available at the moment).

Comment: Relevant: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/full.html#mw_eb1760fd-554a-4bfe-8ddd-5fb592288527

Comment: @Daniel The memory consumed by a `m x n` sparse matrix is: `nnz` reals + `nnz + n + 1` integers, where `nnz` is the number of non-zero elements in the sparse matrix.

Comment: That means that the memory required for the full matrix is 4.65 GB, while the sparse matrix requires 2.79 GB. You will likely run into memory errors with both approaches. [Reference paper](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/otherdocs/simax.pdf).

Comment: 625M elements = about 5GB. If you have 16GB RAM available you should be able to perform all manipulations you listed, while 8GB would require you to use some swap. If you have just 4GB, try `single` instead and some swap. If you have enough ram and it still doesn't work, it is likely you have inefficient code - post it. There might be a trivial fix.

Comment: @ChelseaG.: Looks like you used 32bit for the integers. That is 64 bit for a 64bit MATLAB. I end up with 3.73GB for the sparse matrix, compared to 4.65GB for the full. The important conclusion from the documentation: "In 64-bit MATLAB, however, double matrices with fewer than half of their elements nonzero are more efficient to store as sparse matrices."

Comment: @Daniel good point. OP should also keep in mind that the result of the calculations might result in a non-sparse matrix. If it's still stored as a sparse matrix in MATLAB, then it might actually be better to use `full` after all. `s = sprand(6,6,0.6); p = s*s';` gives / may give a density of 0.94 for `p` as opposed to `0.6` for `s`. This depends on where the nnz element are though.